# Can the Ruby 2.1 shorthand for private/protected be used for class methods?

Tags: ruby, private, protected, ruby-2.1

In Ruby 2.1, `def` now returns a symbol

```
[1] pry(main)> def foo; end
=> :foo
```

One cool use case of this is that because `private` and `protected` are methods that take a symbol and make the method private, you can now [create a private method like so](http://www.sitepoint.com/look-ruby-2-1/):

```
private def foo
end
```

However, I can't get this to work with class methods. This code:

```
protected def self.baz
end
```

will error with: `protected': undefined method 'baz' for class 'User' (NameError)"`.

Is there a way to get that working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`private`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-private) is a method used to mark *instance* methods as private. The equivalent for class methods is [`private_class_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method) so the equivalent idiom would be the somewhat unwieldy and redundant:

```
private_class_method def self.foo
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that by using singleton class of your class:

```
class Foo
  def self.baz
    ...
  end

  class << self
    private :baz
  end
end
```

or in a single attempt:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    private def baz
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

So, everything executed in a `class << self` block will be applied on a class level. Resulting in a private/protected class methods.